# Convert Curl Command to swift using Alamofire

Tags: swift, curl, alamofire, http-authentication

For the past week I have been trying to get an authentication token from a third party webservice by using their API with Alamofire. I have implemented different types of solutions. The problem is the web service only provides documentation on how to connect to their service using `curl`. But I want to connect to it using Alamofire because I am developing an iOS app.

Down below I have posted the different solutions I have implemented that come back with 400 status code or 404. Would someone be kind enough to guide me thru this?

Here is the `curl` command I want to convert to swift using Alamofire:

```
curl "https://api.webservice.com/oauth/token?client_id=<your-client-id>&client_secret=<your-client-secret>&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

In order to receive an access token from the authentication client you have to provide it with a client ID and client secret that is provided.

And here is some of the solutions I have tried implementing:

```
func doAuth(){
    let parameters = ["ClientID": clientID, "clientSecret": clientSecret]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.everypixel.com/oauth/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{
                print(response.result.value as Any)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
    }

    let user = clientID
    let password = clientSecret
    let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(base64Credentials)"]
    print(credentialData)
    Alamofire.request(tokenRequestURL,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: nil,
                      encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                      headers:headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.value != nil{
                print(response)
            }else{

                print("found an error")
            }
    }

    let response = Alamofire.request(tokenRequestURL, method: .get).authenticate(user: clientID, password: clientSecret).response?.statusCode
    print(response)


    let key = clientID
    let secret = clientSecret

    let url = tokenRequestURL

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("sso-key \(key):\(secret)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Data is empty")
            return
        }

        print(response)
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using `method: .post`, where it is not needed. Also there are some wrong parameter names (e.g. `"ClientID": clientID` should be renamed to  `"client_id": clientID`). This might be a cause of 400 or 404 status codes.

At least this GET request worked for me without 400 or 404 status codes:

```
Alamofire
        .request(
            "https://api.everypixel.com/oauth/token",
            parameters:[
                "client_id"     : clientID,
                "client_secret" : clientSecret,
                "grant_type"    : "client_credentials"
            ]
        )
        .responseString { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("from .success \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```